# What is the meaning of Manny's answer?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, cloudy-with-a-chance-of-meatballs-2

In **Cloudy with a Chance of Meatballs 2 (2013)**, Manny prepared his Gorilla Stew & one of the Flint group asks him "How do you prepare it", for that he replied differently.

> Questioner: So how do you make a gorilla stew?
>
> Manny: **You keep it waiting for two hours**.

What is the meaning of Manny's answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### It's a joke.

Here, "How do you make a gorilla stew?" is being used in the context that "stew" means *"[**make angry**](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/stew)"*...so "How do you make a Gorilla angry" can be substituted.

How would you make someone angry?...Make them wait for two hours.